# Remove Unicode literals in a Dataframe string

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe, replace, unicode

I have a Dataframe with resumes in, but they contain Unicode literals such as `"\xe2\x80\x93"`.

I want to remove all of these values to prepare the text for processing.
My issue is that I have tried many recommended ways to remove these, and none seem to work when applied to the data in my df.

---

## Text example:

> "COMPETENCIES\nBenefits Administration \xe2\x80\x93 Customer Service
>   \xe2\x80\x93 Cost Control \xe2\x80\x93 Recruiting \xe2\x80\x93 Acquisition Management"

The part I am finding difficult is if I take this text and put it in a string variable such as `y = <text>` then using one of the following methods to deal with unicode literals:

```
 print(re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F+]',' ', y)

 print(y.encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode('ascii'))
```

It will output:

> "CORE COMPETENCIES
>   Benefits Administration  Customer Service  Cost Control  Recruiting  Acquisition Management"

As expected.

---

When I try this on the values in my Dataframe it simply does not seem to work.
I have tried the following (df is called `resume`):

````
 resume = resume.apply(lambda x : re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F+]',' ',x))

 resume = resume.apply(x.encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode('ascii')

 resume = resume.replace(re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F+]',' ',x)```
````

I have even tried:

```
for x in resume:
    x = str(x)
    x = (re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F+]',' ', x))
    print(x)
```

and:

```
 print(re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F+]',' ', resume[0])
```

Just to see if I could replicate the change when I apply these to a string variable but still no luck.

The dataframe is shape (368,0)
The dtype is object which I have tried converting to string but I believe it always stays as object.

Comment: Try `resume = resume.replace(regex=r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', value=' ')`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't change the Dataframe, I then tried:

`resume = resume.replace(regex=r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', value=' ', inplace=True)`

Which gave "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'"

Comment: If you use `inplace`, you can't assign, use `resume.replace(regex=r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', value=' ', inplace=True)`

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. Without assigning I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to accept UTF-8 text and see the "en-dash" that that represents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
df['text_clean'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('unicode_escape').\
                                          encode('ascii', 'ignore').\
                                          strip())
```

Assumptions:
The dataframe(df) has a 'text' column containing the resume strings with unicode literals.

This is how I tested it:

```
import pandas as pd

# created sample data - same example row inserted 5 times. Not ideal but just was trying to test
df = pd.DataFrame({"text": [b"COMPETENCIES\nBenefits Administration \xe2\x80\x93 Customer Service \xe2\x80\x93 Cost Control \xe2\x80\x93 Recruiting \xe2\x80\x93 Acquisition Management", 
b"COMPETENCIES\nBenefits Administration \xe2\x80\x93 Customer Service \xe2\x80\x93 Cost Control \xe2\x80\x93 Recruiting \xe2\x80\x93 Acquisition Management", 
b"COMPETENCIES\nBenefits Administration \xe2\x80\x93 Customer Service \xe2\x80\x93 Cost Control \xe2\x80\x93 Recruiting \xe2\x80\x93 Acquisition Management", 
b"COMPETENCIES\nBenefits Administration \xe2\x80\x93 Customer Service \xe2\x80\x93 Cost Control \xe2\x80\x93 Recruiting \xe2\x80\x93 Acquisition Management", 
b"COMPETENCIES\nBenefits Administration \xe2\x80\x93 Customer Service \xe2\x80\x93 Cost Control \xe2\x80\x93 Recruiting \xe2\x80\x93 Acquisition Management"]})


df['text_clean'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('unicode_escape').\
                                          encode('ascii', 'ignore').\
                                          strip())
```

Testing the code with kaggle source file:

```
# path stores the location of the data file downloaded from kaggle
df = pd.read_csv(path)

# remove the binary 'b' prefix reinstated even though the data is 
# read as string during df creation
df['Resume'] = [val[1:].encode('utf-8') for val in df['Resume']]

# create a separate column with multiple decode and encode steps to 
# retrieve the final clean version
df['text_clean'] = df['Resume'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('unicode_escape').\
    encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8').strip())

print(df['text_clean'])
```

Output Sample:

```
0       'John H. Smith, P.H.R.\n800-991-5187 | PO Box ...
1       'Name Surname\nAddress\nMobile No/Email\nPERSO...
2       'Anthony Brown\nHR Assistant\nAREAS OF EXPERTI...
3       'www.downloadmela.com\nSatheesh\nEMAIL ID:\nCa...
4       "HUMAN RESOURCES DIRECTOR\nExpert in organizat...
5       'John H. Smith, P.H.R.\n800-991-5187 | PO Box ...
6       'Resume of Satheesh\n\nwww.downlo\nSatheesh\n\...
7       "GM HR & ADMINISTRATION Resume Sample www.time...
8       "www.uaehrzone.com\n\nRobert Wales\nDubai\nUni...
9       "Human Resources Coordinator Resume\nExample\n...
10      'RESUME WORLD INC.\n1200 Markham Road, Suite 1...
11      'XXXXX XXXXX\nXXXX, Renton, WA 98059\nHome: XX...
12      'SATHEESH\n\nwww.downloadmela.com\n\nObjective...
13      'Alan Bloggs BE\n1Main Street, Irish Town, Co....
14      'www.downloadmela.com\nSatheesh\nSummary\n4+ y...
15      'Anthony Brown\nHR Assistant\nAREAS OF EXPERTI...
16      'T\n\nAYLOR J ONES\n15 Jinglewood Street Melbo...
17      'Human Resources Manager\nCurriculum Vitae Exa...
18      'EDMONDBRADY\n1900SummersDriveMontello,AZ55996...
19      'Jonathan Burns\n1414 Marcy Drive\n\n\n\nSomet...
20      'Jo Sample\n123 Ocean Drive\nSampleville, FL 1...
21      'Jonathan Burns\n1414 Marcy Drive\n\n\n\nExamp...
22      'Shweta XXX\nMobile: +91-98********\n\nE-mail:...
23      'www.downloadmela.com\n\nSATHEESH\nMobile :\nE...
24      "Steven B. Manning\n3249 Oral Lake Road\nMinne...
25      "www.downloadmela.com\nSatheesh\n\nE-mail:\nHa...
26      "Resume for HR Assistant\nTX\n3 Avenue,\nSale,...
27      'RESUME WORLD INC.\n1200 Markham Road, Suite 1...
28      'HOW TO WRITE A PROFESSIONAL RESUME\n\n

                                               RESUM...
29      'RESUME WORLD INC.\n1200 Markham Road, Suite 1...
                              ...                        
1189    'Joseph Andrade\nACTOR\nEmail: Jfandrade192@ou...
1190    'MARIAH FORD\nHeight: 5 4\nStars Talent Studio...
1191    'Your Name\nPhone number\nEmail address\nHeigh...
1192    'Jarien Sky-Stutts  Senior 3D Artist\n\ncontac...
1193    "Gary White\nMake up artist\nAREAS OF EXPERTIS...
1194    'RESUME\nDan Platt\n5134 Oakdale Ave.\nWoodlan...
1195    "Jeff Wolverton, M.S., B.S.Cis.\nVisual FX Art...
1196    'LETA LOU GRAY\t\n\r\n\n\t\n\r\n\n\t\n\r\n\n\t...
1197    'Curriculum Vitae\nPersonal Details\n\nDarren ...
1198    'Your Name\n\nSchool Address\n123 Main Street\...
1199    'Stacy Adams\nSAG/AFTRA\nHeight:\nWeight:\nHai...
1200    'PERFORMING ARTS RESUME\nContent\nA performers...
1201    'ED WEISS\nTeaching Artist Resume\n\ne-mail: W...
1202    '8/23/2016 sample resume for painter. accounti...
1203    'KELSEY PAINTER\nBlonde Hair/Brown Eyes | Alto...
1204    'Wendy Robin\nProfessional Make-up Artist\n(70...
1205    'Chet Bailey\n100 Desert Street\nDrytown, CA 9...
1206    'Chris Flight Attendant\n11223 East South Aven...
1207    'Bilingual Flight Attendant Resume\n\nANGELICA...
1208    'Flight Attendant Resumes\nFlight-Attendant-Ca...
1209    'Emirates Flight Attendant Resume Sample\n\nAn...
1210    'Entry Level Flight Attendant Resume  No Exper...
1211    'CURRICULUM VITAE\nMay 11, 2004\n\nNAME\n\nRob...
1212    'JED REDD\n\n_\n003 Boudry Lane\nFriend, TX 77...
1213    'Lauren B. Pires\nMiami, Florida & New York Ci...
1214    "Free Flight Attendant Resume\nDarlene Flint\n...
1215    'Corporate Flight Attendant Resume\nCAITLIN FL...
1216    'MAJOR CONRAD A. PREEDOM\n2354 Fairchild Dr., ...
1217    'STACY SAMPLE\n\n702 800-0000 cell\n\n0000@ema...
1218    'Entry Level Resume Guide\n\nThis packet is in...
Name: text_clean, Length: 1219, dtype: object
```

Comment: Interesting, I get the "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error when trying this

Comment: can you share sample data from your dataframe in copy-pastable format in your question above?

Comment: I actually got the data-set from this link if you have a kaggle profile you can download it: https://www.kaggle.com/maitrip/resumes
I extracted the resume column into a separate dataset that has all the text in, perhaps you could also try it on this dataset?

Comment: I have tested it with the csv from kaggle and added the observations to my answer above.

Comment: fantastic this worked! Was it the 'b' prefix preventing my previous attempts at replacing the Unicode?

Comment: Could be. The way I approach the solution is to go step by step and review the intermittent output. That is how I found that its a string but with a 'b' prefix.